# Multi-variable for-loop declaration in Java

Tags: java, for-loop

What is the correct declaration of multi-variable for-loop declaration in Java?

1. `for (int a = 1; int b = 1; a <= 5; a++; b++)`
2. `for (int a = 1, b = 1; a <= 5; a++; b++)`

Different books uses different declaration.

I used both of them but in both cases, it resulted in syntax error.

Comment: *`Different books uses different declaration.  I used both of them but in both cases, it resulted in syntax error`.*  Assuming you copied the examples correctly, you now know what books not to use.

Comment: In the 'loop control' part of an if-statement there are 3 parts separated by semicolons.  Therefore, anything with more than 2 semicolons is wrong. Easy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    for (int a = 1, b = 1; a <= 5; a++, b++) {
        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(b);
    }
```

Notice it should be `a++, b++` and not `a++ ; b++`

Answer (score 1):

Option (c). Like,

```
for (int a = 1, b = 1; a <= 5; a++, b++) {
    System.out.printf("a=%d, b=%d%n", a, b);
}
```

Which outputs

```
a=1, b=1
a=2, b=2
a=3, b=3
a=4, b=4
a=5, b=5
```

Normally you would change the initial condition and increment for `b` if you wanted to use this form.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize multiple variables (a and b in your example) separated by commas and your loop will continue as long as the condition `(a <= 5)` is `true`, and the increment expressions `(a++ and b++)` will be executed after each iteration of the loop:

```
for (int a = 1, b = 1; a <= 5; a++, b++)
```